# Is there a possibility to rewrite the recipient_delimiter in postfix

Tags: postfix, configuration, dovecot, sieve

I use email address suffixes to file emails to different folders. For example, me+suffix@example.com would be filed in folder "suffix". This works, but I would also like to allow for "-" as recipient_delimiter.

My understanding is that postfix allows for multiple separators. I can, for example, write `recipient_delimiter = +-`

However, this does not work together with dovecot (v.2.2.27 on my system), which allows only for a single delimiter. Therefore I can either use "+" or "-", but not both at the same time.

I now wonder whether there is a possibility in postfix to rewrite a "+" to a "-", or vice versa, before it is handled by dovecot.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: not yet, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `canonical` mapping can be used to rewrite delimiters.

```
# in main.cf
canonical_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/recipient_delimiter.pcre
```

e.g. to remap all dashes into plus, use a regular expression like this:

```
# in recipient_delimiter.prcre
/^(.*)-(.*)@example\.org$/  ${1}+${2}@example.org
```

For single-character delimiters, such rewriting should no longer be needed, as **after Dovecot version 2.3.0+ the `recipient_delimiter` works similar to how it works in Postfix**:

> The recipient_delimiter is treated as multiple one-character
> delimiters rather than one multi-character delimiter if more than one
> character is supplied. The address is split on the first character in
> recipient_delimiter found. -- [Commit: Support multiple recipient_delimiters](https://github.com/dovecot/core/commit/972c9172e9e6a0fc6053efb3d2ee9d354b67727f)